# How to fix: Epson wireless networked printer aborts after printing half a page

Tags: wireless, networking, printing, epson

Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS

Epson Stylus TX550W multifunction printer (copies, scans, but no fax): The first time I managed to discover the printer on my wireless LAN. However, when printing the Ubuntu Test Page, only one-third was printed, then the printer stopped.

Then I installed these deb-packages:

```
epson-inkjet-printer-stylus-tx550w-series_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb
openprinting-gutenprint_5.2.7-1lsb3.2_i386.deb
epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.4.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb
iscan_2.29.3-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb
iscan-data_1.27.0-1_all.deb
iscan-network-nt_1.1.1-1_i386.deb
```

When I search for new printers at 192.168.0.2 (found from my WiFi routers page), it "finds" an HP Laser JetDirect (?).

If I put `socket://192.168.0.2` in the URI or host box, it starts Foomatic and I can choose manufacturer (Epson), model (Stylus TX550W), and a choice of CUPS, Gutenprint, or special Seiko Linux drivers.

But it still prints only one third of any page, whether it be from a brower, LibreOffice, or Ubuntu Test Page, before it stops. The status can be *Stopped* or *Stopped - bad printer configuration*.

Does anybody know what to do?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I discovered that the Netgear wireless router was too far away from the printer and too many packets were being dropped, so that the print process timed out. Putting the printer closer to the router fixed the problem.

Now that we have moved house, the 'line of sight' to the printer is better and we have experienced no problems at all.